# Angular window injecting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, commonjs, umd

Is it possible prevent angular instance inject into global (window) scope when being required and bundled with webpack for example or any other module bundler?

I have found that current main javascript file in angular npm package is:

```javascript
require('./angular');
module.exports = angular;
```

My webpack entry file contents is:

```javascript
import angular from 'angular';

// my custom code goes here
```

So, the main webpack task is to prevent leaking variables to global scope, but if I try to log angular in Chrome DevTools like this:

```javascript
console.log(angular); // => Object {version: Object, callbacks: Object}
```

I will see, that angular instance is injected. Any ideas to prevent this?

**Additional info:**
Angular.js version - 1.6.0-rc.0
Webpack version - 2.1.0-beta.27

Update.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's hard coded into the published NPM code to assign the global Angular variable to the `window` object no matter what:

```
angular           = window.angular || (window.angular = {})
```

So there's no direct way to prevent it from happening. You could always `delete window.angular` after you load it, but no promises that won't affect the library.

Comment: My idea is preventing angular instance injecting to global scope for using different versions of angular on one page. I dont thing deleting angular variable in window object is suitable for me.

Comment: So the only way to do what I want is editing angular sources?

Comment: You can try storing it as a variable `var localAngular = window.angular; delete window.angular` after the require, then requiring the other version. However requiring two versions of angular sounds like a nightmare and I would just not do that

Comment: Yea, two versions of angular on one page sounds weird, but main website has old version of angular, and widget I created to add on main website is using the latest version, so there are a lot of conflicts when switching main website to the latest angular version, huh. But thank you for answer.